# Disable options in NgOptions within an NgRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to disabled already selected options within each "section" (reset with each ng-repeat loop), but I cannot figure out how to best address this situation.

I know that I should use 'disabled when' but cannot figure out how to create that (array?) or track when each select options was already chosen (and make it disabled for the other select within that ngRepeat loop. I need to allow the ability to select the same select option in the section "section."

Any advice is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!
I learn best by example and hopefully this will be beneficial to others learning AngularJS.

As seen in this plunker: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ubmzryLImrYvbm5rqJ1I?p=preview)

I have the following AngularJs markup

```
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="main">
  <hr>
  <div ng-repeat="section in sections track by section.sectionid" ng-model="section.sectionid">
    <p>Section</p>
    <div ng-model="typeModel" ng-repeat="type in types | filter:section.sectionid">
      <p>item name</p>
      <select ng-model="itemSelected" ng-options="item.name for item in items track by item.id">

      </select>

    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use disable syntax `disable when condition` for `ng-options`, **[documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)**(quick search by keyword:`disable when`).

```
ng-options="item.name disable when item.name==='2' for item in items track by item.itemid"
```

**UPD:**

for your situation, you can maintenance an `object` with keys of `sectionid` (easy to set and get by sectionid) and for each of the section, dynamically generate disable conditions for each `select` element.

```
// object looks like this
$scope.sectionSelectedItem = {
  1: [
    concition1,       // for first select of sectionid(1)
    concition2,        // for second select of sectionid(1)
    ... 
  ],
  2: [
    concition1,       // for first select of sectionid(2)
    concition2,        // for second select of sectionid(2)
    ... 
  ],
  ...
}
```

and every time you change a section's `select` element, you can generate condition data for current section by `ng-change`.

Plunker [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/d5KYqWVZgWPtu4qASGRE?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do this dynamically across sections?

Comment: @spookybot you can change the disable conditions according yo your sections.

Comment: @spookybot see the example again, I have add special condition to your `types` array.

Comment: The example doesn't work as expected. When I select an option it should be disabled in the neighbor select

Comment: I also can't modify the existing array per the business model. Thanks for your help

Comment: @spookybot you can maintenance a local array to keep selected items of select.  so you want to disable the current selected item for the next select element?

Comment: I think local array is what i need. I want to disabled the already selected option(s) for the next select options, but need to reset that for the next section.

Comment: @spookybot sorry for late response. I just came up with a idea. check my updated example. I'll explain later for I'm going meeting right now.

Comment: This doesn't account for growth. What if there are more select elements in each section?

Comment: @spookybot I just test it with 3 section * 5 select option. I don't think this will break according to counts of options.  maybe you should explain more. :)

Comment: my scenerio changed enough to post a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038257/disable-ngoptions-based-on-ngchange-update-of-value-in-array

Comment: @spookybot ok, I just took a glance over there. and I don't think you need to delete this one since they are not duplicate ones.

Comment: @spookybot I'm going out for launch now. will deep consider your new question when I'm back.