# Disable ngOptions based on ngChange update of value in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm attempting to **disabled options in a select after they've already been selected**. This is dependent on the 'perf_no' associated with each 'cusomter_no' as seen in the following code. The ngChange updates the value of 'disabled' in the associated object while it's still updating the model. ngModelOptions of debounce does not work for me. **Is there a way to have a callback after the ngChange is finished to update the value of 'disabled' for that object? Or perhaps a much better way to achieve this?** Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="session-registrant-field field-dropdown">
      <label for="">{{nameLbl}}</label>
      <select
      ng-model="affiliateSelected[cartPerf.perf_no][$index]"
      ng-change="changedAffiliate(affiliateSelected, cartPerf.perf_no, $index, affiliateSelected[cartPerf.perf_no][$index].customer_no)" 
      ng-options="affiliate.fname + ' ' + affiliate.lname disable when affiliate.disabled for affiliate in affiliates | filter:cartPerf.perf_no | orderBy:affiliate.customer_no:true track by affiliate.customer_no"
      required>
        <option value="" disabled="">-- Select person --</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

The controller snippet

```
$scope.affiliates = [
    {"id":"1","perf_no":"154","perf_dt":"2017-09-18T10:00:00","customer_no":"-10003","fname":"","lname":"Add New Child","validation_pass_age":"Y","validation_pass_prereq":"Y","ask_birthdate":"Y","ask_current_grade":"Y","ask_next_grade":"Y","ask_email":"N","bdatereq":"Y","age_validation_ind":"Y","min_age":"10","max_age":"25","rel_type_id":"10003"},
  {"id":"2","perf_no":"154","perf_dt":"2017-09-18T10:00:00","customer_no":"-10002","fname":"","lname":"Add New Adult","validation_pass_age":"Y","validation_pass_prereq":"Y","ask_birthdate":"Y","ask_current_grade":"Y","ask_next_grade":"Y","ask_email":"N","bdatereq":"Y","age_validation_ind":"Y","min_age":"10","max_age":"25","rel_type_id":"10002"},
  {"id":"3","perf_no":"154","perf_dt":"2017-09-18T10:00:00","customer_no":"2762","fname":"Ryan","lname":"Jones","age":"22","validation_pass_age":"Y","validation_pass_prereq":"Y","ask_birthdate":"Y","ask_current_grade":"N","ask_next_grade":"N","ask_email":"Y","birthdate":"07\/13\/1995","bdatereq":"Y","eaddress":"","age_validation_ind":"Y","min_age":"10","max_age":"25","rel_type_id":"10003"},
  {"id":"4","perf_no":"154","perf_dt":"2017-09-18T10:00:00","customer_no":"2700","fname":"John","lname":"Doe","age":"","validation_pass_age":"Y","validation_pass_prereq":"Y","ask_birthdate":"Y","ask_current_grade":"N","ask_next_grade":"N","ask_email":"Y","birthdate":"02\/22\/1988","bdatereq":"Y","eaddress":"","age_validation_ind":"Y","min_age":"10","max_age":"25","rel_type_id":"10003"},
  {"id":"5","perf_no":"154","perf_dt":"2017-09-18T10:00:00","customer_no":"2701","fname":"Rick","lname":"Deckard","age":"","validation_pass_age":"Y","validation_pass_prereq":"Y","ask_birthdate":"Y","ask_current_grade":"N","ask_next_grade":"N","ask_email":"Y","birthdate":"02\/22\/1988","bdatereq":"Y","eaddress":"","age_validation_ind":"Y","min_age":"10","max_age":"25","rel_type_id":"10002"},
  {"id":"1","perf_no":"93","perf_dt":"2017-09-18T10:00:00","customer_no":"-10003","fname":"","lname":"Add New Child","validation_pass_age":"Y","validation_pass_prereq":"Y","ask_birthdate":"Y","ask_current_grade":"Y","ask_next_grade":"Y","ask_email":"N","bdatereq":"Y","age_validation_ind":"Y","min_age":"10","max_age":"25","rel_type_id":"10003"},
  {"id":"2","perf_no":"93","perf_dt":"2017-09-18T10:00:00","customer_no":"-10002","fname":"","lname":"Add New Adult","validation_pass_age":"Y","validation_pass_prereq":"Y","ask_birthdate":"Y","ask_current_grade":"Y","ask_next_grade":"Y","ask_email":"N","bdatereq":"Y","age_validation_ind":"Y","min_age":"10","max_age":"25","rel_type_id":"10002"},
  {"id":"3","perf_no":"93","perf_dt":"2017-09-18T10:00:00","customer_no":"2762","fname":"Ryan","lname":"Jones","age":"22","validation_pass_age":"Y","validation_pass_prereq":"Y","ask_birthdate":"Y","ask_current_grade":"N","ask_next_grade":"N","ask_email":"Y","birthdate":"07\/13\/1995","bdatereq":"Y","eaddress":"","age_validation_ind":"Y","min_age":"10","max_age":"25","rel_type_id":"10003"},
  {"id":"4","perf_no":"93","perf_dt":"2017-09-18T10:00:00","customer_no":"2700","fname":"John","lname":"Doe","age":"","validation_pass_age":"Y","validation_pass_prereq":"Y","ask_birthdate":"Y","ask_current_grade":"N","ask_next_grade":"N","ask_email":"Y","birthdate":"02\/22\/1988","bdatereq":"Y","eaddress":"","age_validation_ind":"Y","min_age":"10","max_age":"25","rel_type_id":"10003"}
]

$scope.changedAffiliate = function(selectedItem, cartPerfNo, index, affiliateCustomer_no) {
  $.each($scope.affiliates, function(i) {
    if(this.perf_no === cartPerfNo && this.customer_no === affiliateCustomer_no){
      this['disabled'] = true;
    }
  });
}
$scope.getDisableCondition = function(affiliate, cartPerfNo, index){
  $.each($scope.affiliates, function(i) {
    if(this.disabled === true){
      console.log(this);
      return affiliate.customer_no === this.customer_no;
    }
    if(this.disabled === false || this.disabled === undefined){
      return false;
    }
    //console.log(this);

  });
}
```

---

### [Full Plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/saJjfcc6G5Vy7MfCtNCu?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, maybe it's not pretty, but doing its job ([plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/F9JVTpJ1zz0h2F9o8Jvu?p=preview)):

```
    $scope.passMe;

$scope.changedAffiliate = function(selectedItem, cartPerfNo, index, affiliateCustomer_no) {
  if ($scope.passMe) {
    $scope.affiliates.forEach((aff)=>{
      if (aff.perf_no ==  $scope.passMe[0] && aff.customer_no ==  $scope.passMe[2]) {
        selectedItem[$scope.passMe[0]][ $scope.passMe[1]] = aff
      }
    })
    $scope.passMe = null;
  }
  $scope.passMe = [cartPerfNo,index,affiliateCustomer_no]
  $.each($scope.affiliates, function(i) {
    if(this.perf_no === cartPerfNo && this.customer_no === affiliateCustomer_no){
      this['disabled'] = true;
    }
  });

}
```

It's based on fact that changedAffiliate will run 1 additional time after being disabled.